# execute function for an array in express

Tags: javascript, express, for-loop

I am calling a get function to receive something from an API and that works well with just a single item.
But how can I execute the same function for an array of items and send that with express.

my get function:

```
    const getSummonerByName = async name => {
    const response = await axios.get("https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/" + name + "?api_key=" + apiKey)
    return response.data
}
```

my app.get:

```
const users = ["MSPaint%20Picasso", "Volker%20Racho", "GingerAone"]

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const summoner = await lol.getSummonerByName(users[0])
        res.send(summoner)
    }  
    catch(e) {
        return e
    }
})
```

Comment: Try `const summoner = await Promise.all(users.map(user => lol.getSummonerByName(user)))`

Comment: Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Using promise.all and Array.map

```
const summoner = await Promise.all(users.map(getSummonerByName))
```